# Powershell File Compare

Tags: powershell

I am using a PowerShell script to move some files around on some servers.
I want to test if a file I am going to move already exists in the destination.
Not just a file with the same name.

I thought

`Compare-Object $File1 $File2`
Should do it but no matter what the files are it always returns that they are the same
eg.

```
InputObject           SideIndicator                              
-----------           -------------                              
D:\1.gif               =>                                         
D:\1.wma               <=
```

Is there some other way to test if two files are identical?

Comment: You can use DOS (within PS): `**fc.exe "file1" "file2"**` (Note: must be "fc.exe" as "fc" is "format-custom" in PowerShell.) This gives much less cryptic output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess it's going to depend on your definition of "The same"

```
Compare-Object (ls Source\Test.*) (ls Dest\Test.*) -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime
```

That will compare the actual FILE objects by name, length, and modified date.  Adding -IncludeEqual will result in also showing ones that are the same in both places.

If you want to only copy files from "Source" which aren't the same in the "Destination" just do this:

```
Compare-Object (ls $Source) (ls $Destination) -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime -passthru | 
Where { $_.PSParentPath -eq (gi $Source).PSPath } |
Copy-Item $Destination
```

DO NOT start writing scripts that get-content (as suggested by others) to do a file comparison -- you'd be loading everything into memory...

DO consider using robocopy (even though it's command-line syntax is dated). =Þ

Comment: Thank you this is the direction I think I need to go

Answer (score 31):

```
(Get-FileHash $path1).Hash -eq (Get-FileHash $path2).Hash
```

Comment: Is this really better than a years old, accepted solution?

Comment: Yes it is - in some cases. As @Jaykul says, `it depends on your definition of 'the same'`. Example: I have two files whose Name and LastWriteTime differ, but whose content is the same. This solution is the fastest and best way to compare the content of two files (better than `Get-Content` for memory-related reasons described above).

Answer (score 7):

You're just giving two strings to `Compare-Object`, you want the file contents:

```
Compare-Object (gc $File1) (gc $File2)
```

Also the output you're giving does *not* mean that the files are the same.

Comment: also, if files aren't text, `-Raw` parameter to the `gc` should be added

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with `comp.exe` or `fc.exe`?  Just check the $? after calling them to see if the command succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the file contents for equality, given paths `$path1` and `$path2` like so:

```
[io.file]::ReadAllText($path1) -eq [io.file]::ReadAllText($path2)
```

... Though you may choose instead to compare results of the `::ReadAllBytes()` method.

To be honest, I just use [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy), even from PowerShell, when I care about copying only changed-or-added files.

Comment: Yes I started down the Robocopy path but dioscovered it didnt meet my requirements unfortunatly. Obviously this is a common solutionas everything I found with Google seems to lead to RoboCopy.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in what way did Robocopy not meet your requirements?

Comment: Care with this method: you are loading 2 files completely into memory and then comparing them... = very memory demanding

Answer (score 1):

```
compare $file1 $file2 -includeequal -excludedifferent
```

Comment: This compares both strings, not the contents of the file